# Find average and standard deviation of change in values every 10 seconds in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataset of readings from different sensors. The objective is to get the average change and the standard deviation every 10 seconds, across all sensors (i.e. the final output is just timestamp and average change and standard deviation of change)

Since the data is so large, I initially use Spark to process the 200 million rows:

The original data looks like this:

```
>>> df.show(10, False)

+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+
+integerdate   |        event_timestamp|  sensor_id|reading|
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+
|20180703      |2018-07-03 10:32:50.473|      Front|  54.82|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 15:59:50.616|      Front|  54.54|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 14:49:55.718|      Front|  54.64|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 09:30:00.003|       Bore|  55.60|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 15:08:16.099|       Bore|  54.66|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 09:30:54.837|      Atten|  57.08|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 09:40:24.333|      Atten|  57.08|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 10:06:01.027|      Atten|  56.69|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 10:06:28.787|      Atten|  56.70|
|20180703      |2018-07-03 10:14:32.675|      Atten|  56.64|
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+
```

However, as I am only interested in the change in readings, I use Spark's window and analytical function `lag` to get the first reading for each sensor on each day and only the times when the sensor reading changes:

```
>>> df1 = df\
  .withColumn('previous_reading',
              F.lag(df.reading, 1)
              .over(Window.partitionBy('integerdate', 'sensor_id')
                    .orderBy(df.event_timestamp)))\
  .filter((F.col('previous_reading').isNull()) | (F.col('reading') != F.col('previous_reading')))\
  .withColumn('reading_change', F.bround(df.reading - F.col('previous_reading'), 2))\
  .withColumn('previous_timestamp',
              F.lag(df.event_timestamp, 1)
              .over(Window
                    .partitionBy('integerdate', 'sensor_id')
                    .orderBy(df.event_timestamp)))\
  .withColumn('seconds_elapsed',
              time_elapsed_udf(F.struct(df.event_timestamp,
                                        F.col('previous_timestamp'))))

>>> df1.show(10, False)
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+-----------------------+---------------+
|integerdate|event_timestamp        |sensor_id  |reading|previous_reading|reading_change|previous_timestamp     |seconds_elapsed|
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+-----------------------+---------------+
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:32:00.972|Back       |  0.365|null            |null          |null                   |null           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:36:04.096|Anter      |  0.210|null            |null          |null                   |null           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 11:59:17.118|Anter      |  0.250|0.21            |0.04          |2018-07-03 09:36:04.096|8593           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 12:47:40.309|Alloc      |  47.99|null            |null          |null                   |null           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 08:00:13.931|Bore       |  2.730|null            |null          |null                   |null           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:30:00.003|Bore       |  2.750|2.73            |0.02          |2018-07-03 08:00:13.931|5386           |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:30:00.003|Bore       |  2.710|2.75            |-0.04         |2018-07-03 09:30:00.003|0              |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:30:00.697|Bore       |  2.780|2.71            |0.07          |2018-07-03 09:30:00.003|0              |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:32:47.269|Bore       |  2.730|2.78            |-0.05         |2018-07-03 09:30:00.697|166            |
|20180703   |2018-07-03 09:34:50.814|Bore       |  2.760|2.73            |0.03          |2018-07-03 09:32:47.269|123            |
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+----------------+--------------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

This reduces the total number of rows to about 20 million which I can easily process in Pandas.

```
>>> pd_df = df1.toPandas()
>>> pd_df.head(10)

     integerdate  event_timestamp           sensor_id  reading    previous_reading    reading_change        previous_timestamp     seconds_elapsed
0    20180703     2018-07-03 09:32:00.972        Back    0.365                 NaN               NaN                       NaT                 NaN
1    20180703     2018-07-03 09:36:04.096       Anter    0.210                 NaN               NaN                       NaT                 NaN
2    20180703     2018-07-03 11:59:17.118       Anter    0.250                0.21              0.04   2018-07-03 09:36:04.096                8593 
3    20180703     2018-07-03 12:47:40.309       Alloc    47.99                 NaN               NaN                       NaT                 NaN  
4    20180703     2018-07-03 08:00:13.931        Bore    2.730                 NaN               NaN                       NaT                 NaN  
5    20180703     2018-07-03 09:30:00.003        Bore    2.750                2.73              0.02   2018-07-03 08:00:13.931                5386 
6    20180703     2018-07-03 09:30:00.003        Bore    2.710                2.75             -0.04   2018-07-03 09:30:00.003                   0 
7    20180703     2018-07-03 09:30:00.697        Bore    2.780                2.71              0.07   2018-07-03 09:30:00.003                   0 
8    20180703     2018-07-03 09:32:47.269        Bore    2.730                2.78             -0.05   2018-07-03 09:30:00.697                 166  
9    20180703     2018-07-03 09:34:50.814        Bore    2.760                2.73              0.03   2018-07-03 09:32:47.269                 123
```

I think I only need `event_timestamp`, `sensor_id`, `reading` and use pandas `resample()` and use `apply()` to get the change in reading every 10 seconds.

I decided to see `previous_reading`, `previous_timestamp` and `time_elapsed` in my Spark transformation to ensure that the window and `lag()` are working properly.

Now, the challenge is that for some sensors, the reading changes every few microseconds or seconds, but for some sensors the reading does not change for many hours.

How can I use pandas `resample()` to get the change in reading every 10 seconds and then find average change and standard deviation of change in the sensor reading every 10 seconds?

The final output should be in this format:

```
event_timestamp     avg_change  std_dev
2018-07-03 09:00:10       0.05     0.02
2018-07-03 09:00:20       0.21     0.01
2018-07-03 09:00:30       0.58     0.12
2018-07-03 09:00:40       0.71     0.45
2018-07-03 09:00:50       1.14     0.78
2018-07-03 09:01:00       1.05     0.79
2018-07-03 09:01:10       5.05     0.24
2018-07-03 09:01:20       1.96     0.30
2018-07-03 09:01:30       0.51     0.01
2018-07-03 09:01:40       0.14     0.02
```

Let me know if you need more information from me?

Comment: For getting changes over time, it sounds like you might want to use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#time-aware-rolling-vs-resampling) instead of resampling?

Comment: @brennan I have made some progress using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) like so: `pd_df.groupby(['sensor_id']).resample('10S', label='right', on='event_timestamp').last()['reading'].ffill().agg(['diff', 'pct_change'])` - working my way through to the aggregate average and standard deviation for change.